# Toast Notification buttons won't show

Tags: notifications, windows-10, toast

I have a toast notification that needs to have the priority of an alarm. I have found a way of doing that but haven't been able to test this as I have to add a button or otherwise it will still handle the notification as a normal one. I have added the button part but it won't show up.

This is what I have written for the template of my toast notification:

```
param(
    [String] $Title = 'Citrix Workspace'
)

[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null

$DEP = 'ICT'

$template = @"
<toast scenario="alarm">
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastText04">
            <text id="1">$($Title)</text>
            <text id="2">Citrix Workspace will close and update in 5 minutes! Save your progress.</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
    <action
     activationType="system"
     arguments="OK" content=""/>
    </actions>
</toast>
"@

$xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($template)
$toast = New-Object Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification $xml
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($DEP).Show($toast)
```

I have no idea why this won't work. If anyone has an idea or if you need extra info just let me know.
Thanks so much!!

Comment: Your script works fine for me, I have a notification. Perhaps you have disabled notifications for "ITC" in the parameters when the notification appears ? Try with $DEP = 'TEST' to see if you have the same issue

Comment: will definitely try. Thanks!